# Как программно изменить программу?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть Button

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="trap" />
```

при нажатия необходимо подменять код .

**Вот начальный код:**

```
package com.example.a21.ii;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

**при нажатия кнопки изменить  на эту код:**

```
package com.example.a21.ii;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void something(){}
}
```

Не могу найти решение, возможно ли это?

Comment: Вам нужно научиться компилировать Java-код во время исполнения программы. В случае Андроида надо получать не `.class`, а `.dex`-файлы. Вероятно придется воспользоваться сторонними либами, например, [dexmaker](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker) от linkedin.